# Regex matching beginning AND end strings

Tags: regex

This seems like it should be trivial, but I'm not so good with regular expressions, and this doesn't seem to be easy to Google.

I need a regex that starts with the string 'dbo.' and ends with the string '_fn'

So far as I am concerned, I don't care what characters are in between these two strings, so long as the beginning and end are correct.

This is to match functions in a SQL server database.

For example:

```
dbo.functionName_fn - Match

dbo._fn_functionName - No Match

dbo.functionName_fn_blah - No Match
```

Comment: If you are here from a search engine hit looking for ***the opposite*** (because "not" can not be used literally with search engines), see *[What is a regex to match a string NOT at the end of a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475015/)* (it is for Ruby, but it probably still applies for most regular expression environments).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're searching for hits within a larger text, you don't want to use `^` and `$` as some other responders have said; those match the beginning and end of the text.  Try this instead:

```
\bdbo\.\w+_fn\b
```

`\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): it matches a position that is either preceded by a word character and not followed by one, or followed by a word character and not preceded by one.  This regex will find what you're looking for in any of these strings:

```
dbo.functionName_fn
foo dbo.functionName_fn bar
(dbo.functionName_fn)
```

...but not in this one:

```
foodbo.functionName_fnbar
```

`\w+` matches one or more "word characters" (letters, digits, or `_`).  If you need something more inclusive, you can try `\S+` (one or more non-whitespace characters) or `.+?` (one or more of any characters except linefeeds, non-greedily).  The non-greedy `+?` prevents it from accidentally matching something like `dbo.func1_fn dbo.func2_fn` as if it were just one hit.

Comment: I have a question I don;t know whether you know it or not. In flex \b is not supported. Do you have any Idea to implement \b in flex?

Answer (score 34):

```
^dbo\..*_fn$
```

This should work you.

Comment: FYI:  ^ Means the beginning of a string, $ means the end of a string.

Comment: @Daniel A. White what is \..* used for ?

Comment: @eawedat, `\.` is for dot itself, `.*` is for unbounded sequence of any characters.

Comment: just escape it with `\\`

Answer (score 8):

Well, the simple regex is this:

```
/^dbo\..*_fn$/
```

It would be better, however, to use the string manipulation functionality of whatever programming language you're using to slice off the first four and the last three characters of the string and check whether they're what you want.

Comment: Agreed on the string manipulation.  However, I'm using this in CodeSmith Generator, and do not have access to the source.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @onesomeday What is \..* used for ?

Comment: @eawedat It means a literal . character followed by 0 or more of any other characters.

Answer (score 4):

```
\bdbo\..*fn
```

I was looking through a ton of java code for a specific library: `car.csclh.server.isr.businesslogic.TypePlatform` (although I only knew `car` and `Platform` at the time). Unfortunately, none of the other suggestions here worked for me, so I figured I'd post this.

Here's the regex I used to find it:

```
\bcar\..*Platform
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String part = scanner.nextLine();
String line = scanner.nextLine();

String temp = "\\b" + part + "|" + part + "\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(temp.toLowerCase());
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line.toLowerCase());

System.out.println(matcher.find() ? "YES" : "NO");
```

If you need to determine if any of the words of this text start or end with the sequence, you can use this regex: `\bsubstring|substring\b`:

anything*substring* 
*substring*anything 
anythingsubstringanything

Comment: What programming language? [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)? [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is [java](https://www.javatpoint.com/system-out-println-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing that you can do is:

`dbo.*_fn$`

It searches with `dbo`, followed by any characters, and then ends with `_fn`.

If you can identify what’s the right next character after `n` if it’s space, you can replace `$` with space  .