# What is a regex to match a string NOT at the end of a line?

Tags: ruby, regex

The regex `/abc$/` will match an `abc` that does appear at the end of the line. How do I do the inverse?

I want to match `abc` that isn't at the end of a line.

Furthermore, I'm going to be using the regex to replace strings, so I want to capture only `abc`, not anything after the string, so `/abc.+$/` doesn't work, because it would replace not only `abc` but anything after `abc` too.

What is the correct regex to use?

Comment: For a slightly different problem, matching unless a particular character (or set of characters) is at the end of the line (say, underscore (`_`)): `[^_]$`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
/abc(?!$)/
```

`(?!$)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It will look for any match of abc that is not directly followed by a `$` (end of line)

Tested against

- **abc**ddee (match)
- dddeee**abc** (no match)
- adfassdf**abc**s (match)
- f**abc**ddee (match)

applying it to your case:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :007 > "aslkdjfabcalskdfjaabcaabc".gsub(/abc(?!$)/, 'xyz')
  => "aslkdjfxyzalskdfjaxyzaabc"
```

Comment: For anyone else looking for it, in Vim the negative lookahead is [`\@!`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21148678/1717828).

Comment: I needed to replace spaces in the middle and this pattern didn't cut it, but switching the 2 parts did it:

`(?!$)\s`