# Is there a way to do negative lookahead in vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

In Vim, is there a way to search for lines that match say `abc` but do not also contain `xyz` later on the line? So the following lines would match:

```
The abc is the best
The first three letters are abc
```

and the following would not match:

```
The abc is the best but xyz is cheaper
The first three letters are abc and the last are xyz
```

I know about syntax like the following:

```
/abc\(xyz\)\@!
```

but that only avoids matching `abcxyz` and not if there is anything in between, such as `abc-xyz`. Using

```
/abc.*\(xyz\)\@!
```

also does not work because there are many positions later in the line where `xyz` is not matched.

(I should note that on the command line I would do something like `grep abc <infile | grep -v xyz` but I would like to do the above interactively in Vim.)

Comment: why `<infile`  instead of just `infile` ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The **`.*`** allows an arbitrary distance between the *match* and the  *non-match*, which is asserted later.
You need to pull the `.*` into the *negative look-ahead*:

```
/abc\(.*xyz\)\@!
```

**Possible Reason** 
The non-match is attempted for all possible matches of `.*`, and the `\@!` is declared as fulfilled only when all branches have been tried.

Comment: This is equivalent to `abc(?!.*xyz)` in Perl-like engines.

Comment: And this works, because look-ahead simple launches another full-blown search from the current position for the pattern, and use the result to decide whether to continue or not (depending whether the look-ahead is positive or negative).

Comment: also see `:help perl-patterns`. For `pattern2` not preceded by `pattern1`, that is negative look-behind, search for `\(pattern1\)\@<!pattern2`.

Comment: This might be outdated - but it seems to me that the above solution will not work for a string like `xyzabc`. The OP indicated that a line should not have `xyz` *anywhere* in the line. What worked for me is mandated capturing the whole line: `^(?!.*xyz).*abc(?!.*xyz)` (not `vim` format). See [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3if0r)

Comment: This helped me search for change lines in a Terraform plan `/\("[^"]*"\) => \(\1\)\@!`

Answer (score 25):

I always find it weird, that you need to escape brackets in vim, so I try to use the "very magic" mode most of the time, activated with `\v`:

```
/\vabc(.*xyz)@!
```

Comment: So good to know about this, I have been in VIM-Regex hell before

Answer (score 10):

Although your question is about lookahead, I found it while searching for lookbehind. Thus, I post the solution to lookbehind so that others may find it.

If you search for `pattern2` not preceded by `pattern1`, that is negative lookbehind, search for:

```
\(pattern1\)\@<!pattern2
```

Comment: This is equivalent to `(?!pattern1)pattern2` in PCRE.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me `/abc\(.*xyz\)\@!`

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't strict about only using vim regex search, there is another option. You can use global command as following

```
:g/abc/v/xyz/p
```

Explanation

- "g/abc" : scan all lines and mark all matching the pattern
- v/xyz/  : from above results mark all lines not including "xyz" pattern
- p       : print the lines found. You can replace it with another command

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd write this as `/abc\(\(xyz\)\@!.\)*$`

I'm not sure whether this is faster than other suggestions (I think it might be since it tests each position only once) but it makes conceptual sense as:

"abc followed by anything which is not xyz, any number of times until end of line"

I like that better than "abc followed by anything not followed by xyz" as in the other patterns mentioned.