# Find exact number pattern regex not working in Linux vi editor

Tags: regex, editor, vi

I have a regex that finds the consecutive 15 numbers. It works fine in the notepad but when I try to run it on vi editor in Linux, it shows no pattern found. Even though there are numbers of the same length.
Here is the regex I am using.

Regex: `(?<!\d)\d{15}(?!\d)`
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See these pages for the syntax of lookarounds in vim https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148467/is-there-a-way-to-do-negative-lookahead-in-vim-regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391665/vim-positive-lookahead-regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you need to do several things:

- Add `\v` at the start to enable *very magic mode* to avoid over-escaping
- Convert a `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind to `(\d)@<!`
- Convert a `(?!\d)` negative lookahead to `(\d)@!`

```
\v(\d)@<!\d{15}(\d)@!
```