# Regex insert space every third character, except at end of line

Tags: python, regex

Given I want to insert a space after every third character in a string, except for after the last one.

This is how far I got:

```
re.sub('(.{3})','\\1 ',i)
```

But I didn't find an elegant way to skip the last insert, for cases where `len(i)%3=0`.

Any idea?

```
re.sub('(.{3})$-','\\1 ',i)
```

does not help at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10475044/771848) to check that a match is not at the end of the string:

```
In [2]: s = "abcdefghi"

In [3]: re.sub(r'(.{3})(?!$)','\\1 ', s)
Out[3]: 'abc def ghi'
```

---

You can also proceed with a non-regex option by slicing the string and joining the sliced parts:

```
In [4]: " ".join(s[i: i + 3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3))
Out[4]: 'abc def ghi'
```

Comment: Thanks! the first suggestion is exactly what I have been looking for.