# python, re.sub add a white space every 'x' characters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
string = 'ABCDEFGHIJLM'
```

I'm trying to achieve the following result using

```
re.sub(SOME CODE HERE):
'ABC DEF GHI JLM'
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: To format the table/code/error correctly, please add **4 leading** space to each line of the table. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex insert space every third character, except at end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981050/regex-insert-space-every-third-character-except-at-end-of-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match three letters "(\w\w\w)" and replace them with themselves plus a space ("\1 "):

```
print re.sub(r'(\w\w\w)', r'\1 ', 'ABCDEFGHIJLM')
```

Prints:

```
'ABC DEF GHI JLM '
```

To get rid of the trailing space, you can put a negative look-ahead of "Not end of string (?!$)":

```
print re.sub(r'(\w\w\w)(?!$)', r'\1 ', 'ABCDEFGHIJLM')
```

Prints:

```
'ABC DEF GHI JLM'
```

If you want to make the group size a parameter, you can specify the letter count as a quantifier ({n}) after the \w to define the size. E.g.:

```
group_size = 2
print re.sub(r'(\w{%d})(?!$)' % group_size, r'\1 ', 'ABCDEFGHIJLM')
```

Prints:

```
'AB CD EF GH IJ LM'
```

Comment: You need to defined it for a general case of n characters

Answer (score 0):

Use `re findall` and `join` this way:

```
 s='ABCDEFGHIJLM'
 n=3
 pattern= '.'*n 
 ' '.join(re.findall(pattern, s))
'ABC DEF GHI JLM'
```