# Match a string that begins and ends with different text

Tags: java, regex

I'm very new to Regular expressions.
I have a text "**cat**/1.39 bla, **dog**" 
I know that ^ is used to match a string that begins with something and $ is used to match something that ends with something.

This is what I could write -

cat/[^,\s;] --> matches "**cat/1.39 bla,** monkey"
**But "cat/[^,\s;].*dog$" doesn't match a string that begins with a cat and ends with a dog**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thank you.
I Tried that. But it did not work

Comment: @user1799214 Please post your code.

Comment: @user1799214 `"cat/1.39 bla, dog".matches("^cat.*dog$")` returns true...

Answer (score 0):

**^cat..*dog$**

This should work for you. You can test it out [here](https://regex101.com/).

Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381641/regex-matching-beginning-and-end-strings?rq=1) answer  for a sloution using word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

> cat/[^,\s;].*dog$

Note that whitespace after the word "dog" will cause the regex to fail.  So if your string was "cat/1.39 bla, dog   "  your regex (and the "^cat.*dog$" that others have posted will fail.

Also remember that the "^" character inside and at the front of the brackets [] means to match anything but what is inside your brackets [].  Thus [^,\s;] will stop at any of those characters.  So if you have a string like "cat/1.39 bla, dog", the regex will proceed all the way to the "," character and stop. In your case the ".*" should still allow you to continue until you get to "dog".

Also

You can test regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/vP3rJ1/1).  Note that the first line doesn't match because I have added to space characters after the word dog.